# How can i stop click functionality on contact button with window.open in parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div section with `onclick="window.open('detail.html')"` functionality, i want to use this  for open page while click on this whole section, its working fine, i have contact button too. i want to stop click on button. how to prevent it?

```css
.box{ border:1px solid #ccc; padding:25px; cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<div class="box" onclick="window.open('searchDetail.html')">
<h1>Prevent the Default Action for an Event - OpenJS</h1>
<p>The event.preventDefault() method stops the default action of an element from happening. For example: Prevent a submit button from submitting a form. Prevent a link from following the URL.
</p>
<button>Contact</button>
</div>
```

Answer will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a check and only trigger the window.open if the element is not a button

```js
function openWindow(e) {
  if(!e.target.classList.contains("dontOpen") && !e.target.parentElement.classList.contains("dontOpen")) {
  console.log('open');
  window.open('searchDetail.html');
  }
  return false
}
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" onclick="openWindow(event)">
  <h1>Prevent the Default Action for an Event - OpenJS</h1>
  <p>The event.preventDefault() method stops the default action of an element from happening. For example: Prevent a submit button from submitting a form. Prevent a link from following the URL.
  </p>
  <div class="dontOpen class"><button>Contact 1</button> <button>Contact 2</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: but if i want to use "e.target.className" instead of "e.target.tagName", it is not working

Comment: because you don't have a class on the button

Comment: it is working with single class if i added like this `"<button class="dontOpen btn">Contact</button>"` this is not working now.

Comment: use classList if you have multiple classes,see updated answer

Comment: this is working fine but, we need to use like this `<div class="dontOpen class"><button>Contact 1</button> <button>Contact 2</button></div>` and this is not working, can you tell me why this is not working?

Comment: e.target will get the inner most element so you need to go up to its parent to test if the class exist or add the class to each button, see the updated answer

Comment: now its working fine as i want, thank you so much @madalinivascu for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Add a dummy onclick function to the button. It wont go to the new window

```js
function a()
{
return false}
```

```css
.box{ border:1px solid #ccc; padding:25px; cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<div class="box" onclick="window.open('searchDetail.html')">
<h1>Prevent the Default Action for an Event - OpenJS</h1>
<p>The event.preventDefault() method stops the default action of an element from happening. For example: Prevent a submit button from submitting a form. Prevent a link from following the URL.
</p>
<button onclick='a()'>Contact</button>
</div>
```

Comment: its working but "searchDetail.html" this page also open while click on contact button, how to stop it?

Comment: In the snippet it is not going anywhere